# Vector notation - commas

Tags: matrices, vectors, cross-product

I am trying to solve a question that involves matrices and vectors. One part of the question uses the notation $v \times w,v,w$, where w and v are non-collinear vectors in $\mathbf{R}^{3}$.

I am confused by this notation - does $v \times w,v,w$ result in a 3 by 3 matrix with the column vectors $v \times w, v \times v$ and $v \times w$ next to each other? If not, what does it mean?

Comment: It just lists three vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3$, namely $v\times w,v,w$.

Comment: I suppose that the notatin simply means that we have the three vectors $v$,$w$ and $v\times w$.

Comment: Can you provide the context of how this notation is used. I suspect it is exactly as Dietrich says (i.e. it is just listing three things).

Comment: @Dave It was in the context of finding the determinant of said matrix. I managed to work it out after the comments here, I can't believe I missed it before! Thanks.